# PHP based website for executing SQL SERVER query

Tags: php, sql-server

I made a project about a php site that will execute query for sql server.
I'm using sqlserver driver for php and xampp with ODBC driver.
Everything run smoothly for create,select,insert,update,and delete query. But when I tried to backup, it create a .bak (as expected) but only ONCE. When I execute the same code again (with different .bak filename), it didn't create another .bak file.

For the input from the site, i'm using standard html input text and saving it to a variable, then placing it to query sntax such as

```
<input type="text" name="query"></td>
```

And then executing the query using :

```
$stat=sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
```

There's no error about the connection to sql server and every other thing run smoothly.

Comment: You're executing arbitrary SQL code entered by a user on a web page, with high enough privileges to perform a backup? You're very trusting, far more so than anyone I know.

Comment: Does the query run? What IS the query you are running? Did you check for errors? What errors are shown? There's not nearly *relevant* information in your question.